# EOF, EOL and empty space at LC3 assembly

Tags: string, file, assembly, lc3

I would like to make a general question about file reading. When I read strings form a file at an LC3 assembly program, how can I know that EOF is reached, EOL or empty space?

To be more specific, which are the equivalent commands for `while(!=EOF)`, `while(!=EOL)` and `while(!= ' ')` at LC3 assembly? I guess that it it must be related to ASCII coding.

In addition, does 0x0 address mean end of string?

Comment: A space is represented by an ASCII value. EOL is somewhat operating system dependent, but usually involves checking for a line feed (ASCII code) or a combination of carriage return and line feed (both ASCII codes). EOF is usually a condition or result returned by whatever system call you are making which reads input from somewhere (a file or the console, for example). Have a look at, [Converting High-level Programming Concepts to Assembly](http://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs240/fall2013/highlevelprogramming.html).

Comment: Whether `0x0` represents the end of a string is implementation dependent and depends upon the system or library call you are using. It is the convention in C/C++ programming. The library or system call you interact with may or may not follow that convention, so you have to rely on the documentation for those calls. If you're defining the string yourself, then it's totally up to you. Some assemblers support directives which make it easy to define a zero-terminated string (*e.g.*, `.asciiz`).